# How to Edit App.Yaml (Google Cloud Platform)

Tags: google-cloud-platform, deployment, gcloud, app.yaml

I am ready to deploy into the Google Cloud Platform but I have ran into a problem. The website won't deploy. Here is what the code displays:

```
ERROR: (gcloud.app.deploy) An error occurred while parsing file: [/home/jinthemix/app.yaml]
Unexpected attribute 'pi_version' for object of type AppInfoExternal.
  in "/home/jinthemix/app.yaml", line 1, column 13
```

Down below here is the app.yaml. I used vim app.yaml to get into the code. I am confused as to why it looks different from the code I wanted to use. So I am wondering how I can edit app.yaml so I can deploy.

[image: I can't upload the code directly, can't copy and paste]

This is the code I want to use:

```
runtime: python27
api_version: 1
threadsafe: true

handlers:
- url: /
  static_files: www/index.html
  upload: www/index.html

- url: /(.*)
  static_files: www/\1
  upload: www/(.*)
```

(side note: How would I link the index.html? (when someone navigates to the root page of your website, what the person sees when clicking or going to the link of the site)) Here is where the html is located:

```
jinthemix@cloudshell:~ (website-deploying-gc)$ ls
app.yaml  IMD233  Files  README-cloudshell.txt  README.md  www
jinthemix@cloudshell:~ (website-deploying-gc)$ cd www
jinthemix@cloudshell:~/www (website-deploying-gc)$ ls
Mixs
jinthemix@cloudshell:~/www (website-deploying-gc)$ cd Mixs
jinthemix@cloudshell:~/www/Mixs (website-deploying-gc)$ ls
'Mix 1 (1)'  'Mix 2 (2)'  'Mix 3 (3)'  'Mix 4 (4)'
jinthemix@cloudshell:~/www/Mixs (website-deploying-gc)$ cd 'Mix (1)'
jinthemix@cloudshell:~/www/Mixs/Mix 1 (1) (website-deploying-gc)$ ls
'hello.html (B) (L2).html'  'hello.html (T) (L3).html'  'hello (L1).html'
jinthemix@cloudshell:~/www/Mixs/Mix 1 (1) (website-deploying-gc)$ cd
jinthemix@cloudshell:~ (website-deploying-gc)$ cd
```

Comment: 1) The beginning of `app.yaml` is missing. Use `vi` to type in the missing part. Are you trying to say you do not know how to use vi? If yes, there are lots of getting started tutorials on the Internet. 2) Replace the last section of your question with the output from this command `find . -print`. That will create a clean listing of files and subdirectories. 3) Do not ask multiple questions in one post. Create one well defined question. Create separate posts for each question.

Comment: Appreciate the help. I guess I didn't realize that (about the added question), new to stack overflow. Any examples of using vi in the scenario provided in the question?

Comment: Did you search for a tutorial on how to use vi?

Comment: I got a general idea: typing in vi app.yaml, type up the desired code, pressing (CTRL + O), then pressing :wq to save and quit. Hopefully afterwards, the deploy will work.

Comment: Can you type up the code like a Word doc (like clicking on a specific sentence of code)? Also, where do I type "find . -print"? Inside the app.yaml?

Comment: `find` is a Linux command that you execute from the shell. It has nothing to do with `app.yaml`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general you could use any text editor program that can read [YAML files](https://yaml.org/) to edit any app.yaml files.

I see you are using the Cloud Shell to deploy your application.

You could use any text editor supported by UNIX (e.g. [vim](https://www.vim.org/) or [nano](https://www.nano-editor.org/dist/v2.2/nano.html)) and edit the file from the terminal by running the relevant commands each program uses to open and then save the edited file.

If you find using any of the above programs from the terminal challenging and prefer a more  visual friendly interface take advantage of the Cloud Shell Editor by following the steps mentioned on the [docs](https://cloud.google.com/shell/docs/editor-overview#viewing_and_editing_files) (basically just click on the Open editor button on the Cloud Shell, locate the file  and edit it as if you were using Notepad).

Comment: I didn't know that the Cloud Shell Editor had a feature, make editing much easier. Appreciate the help

Comment: It was a relatively recent addition.